# Google Calendar API Request not Going Through with Node.js (Express) + Request Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am writing a server that employs the Google Calendar API. I have made one successful request, but this `POST` request that [is supposed to create a new Calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) returns the following error in the HTTP response body:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required"
 }
}
```

I am using Node.js, Express, and a wrapper of Node's HTTP library called [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) (by Mikeal) to make the requests to Google's API. I only ask this question because the error message is quite cryptic. If anyone could help figure this out, that would be great!

Some code samples are included below to help understand more:

**setupTasksCalendar method (makes the request to create a new Calendar):**

```
var setupTasksCalendar = function(req, callback) {
    Oauth.makeApiCall({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        summary: "Google Calendar Tasks"
      })
    }, req, function(e, body) {
      if (e) console.log(e);
      console.log(body);
      callback();
    });
  };
```

**makeApiCall method (a wrapper method that makes the needed checks and adds the auth token to the URL):**

```
this.makeApiCall = function(parameters, req, callback) {
    if (Date.now() >= req.session.user.token_expiration_time) {
      self.Auth.updateAccessToken(req, function() {
        parameters.url = self.addAccessToken(parameters.url, req);
        request(parameters, function(e, r, body) {
          if (e) console.log(e);
          callback(e, body);
        });
      });
    } else {
      parameters.url = self.addAccessToken(parameters.url, req);
      request(parameters, function(e, r, body) {
        if (e) console.log(e);
        callback(e, body);
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Visiting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars manually gives me the same response. Are you supposed to include your API key or something?

Comment: I included my access_token in the request, if that is what you are asking. I know that `makeApiCall` function works with other requests because I have successfully made those other requests, and that function adds the access_token to the URL automatically; I don't think it is that.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct url?

Comment: positive. I just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! It turns out that just putting the JSON in the body wasn't enough: I needed to make sure the request had `application/json` as the `content-type`. To do this in Request, you had to...

replace this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    summary: "Google Calendar Tasks"
    })
```

with this:

```
json: {
    summary: "Google Calendar Tasks"
    }
```